# Automating Parsing XML Into Logstash

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm attempting to collect the items in an XML file in order to index and search call detail records from our phone system, but I think my lack of Xpath experience is causing issues. What I'd like is to have each item under the record stored as a field in the Elastic log, but all I seem to get are blanks or random strings that don't match my actual records. Here is a copy of my Logstash pipeline:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "PATH"
    mode => "read"
    file_completed_action => "delete"
    id => "metaxml"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "<Call "
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
filter {
  xml {
    remove_namespaces => true
    store_xml => false
    source => "[message]"
    force_array => false
    xpath =>{ "//Call/*/text()" => "Call" }
  }
  ruby {
    code => '
    x = event.get("xml_value")
    if x
    x.each { |k, v|
      newk = k.gsub(/(?!^)([A-Z])/, "_\1")
      newk = newk.downcase
      event.remove("[xml_value][#{k}]")
      event.set("[xml_value][#{newk}]", v)
    }
  end
  '
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    cloud_id => REDACTED
    cloud_auth => REDACTED
    index => "cdrs"
  }
}
```

This is monitoring a path on a server looking for XML files. Here is an example that has sensitive data redacted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xmlns="http://www.metaswitch.com/cfs/billing/V1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" compatibility="13">
<FileHeader seqnum="58399">
<EquipmentType>Metaswitch CFS</EquipmentType>
<EquipmentId></EquipmentId>
<CreateTime>1601447977925</CreateTime>
</FileHeader>
<CDRs>
<Call seqnum="0000000001" error="no" longcall="false" testcall="false" class="0" operator="false" correlator="2232808100743" connected="true">
<CallType>Unknown</CallType>
<Features>
<Feature>LegPartOfForwardedCall</Feature>
</Features>
<ReleasingParty>Orig</ReleasingParty>
<ReleaseReason type="q850" loc="ln">16</ReleaseReason>
<ReleaseReason type="internal">No error</ReleaseReason>
<InternalIndex>194739963</InternalIndex>
<OrigParty xsi:type="NetworkTrunkPartyType" privacy="false">
<TrunkGroup type="sip" trunkname="REDACTED">
<TrunkGroupId>1200</TrunkGroupId>
<TrunkMemberId>0</TrunkMemberId>
</TrunkGroup>
<CallingPartyAddr type="e164">+15555555555</CallingPartyAddr>
<SIPCallId>REDACTED@REDACTED</SIPCallId>
</OrigParty>
<TermParty xsi:type="MLHGPilotPartyType" subscribergroup="Subscribers" billingtype="msg rate" privacy="no indication">
<SubscriberAddr type="e164">+15555555555</SubscriberAddr>
<CallingPartyAddr type="e164">+15555555555</CallingPartyAddr>
<ChargeAddr type="e164">+15555555555</ChargeAddr>
<BusinessGroupNameREDACTED-5555555555</BusinessGroupName>
</TermParty>
<RoutingInfo>
<RequestedAddr type="unknown">5555555555</RequestedAddr>
<DestAddr type="e164">+15555555555</DestAddr>
<RoutedAddr type="national">5555555555</RoutedAddr>
<CallingPartyRoutedAddr type="national">5555555555</CallingPartyRoutedAddr>
<CallingPartyOrigAddr type="national">5555555555</CallingPartyOrigAddr>
</RoutingInfo>
<SignalingInfo>
<MediaCapabilityRequested>Speech</MediaCapabilityRequested>
</SignalingInfo>
<IcSeizeTime>1601447908231</IcSeizeTime>
<OgSeizeTime/>
<RingingTime>1601447908239</RingingTime>
<ConnectTime>1601447912729</ConnectTime>
<DisconnectTime>1601447994022</DisconnectTime>
<ReleaseTime>1601447994021</ReleaseTime>
<CompleteTime>1601447994022</CompleteTime>
</Call>
<Call seqnum="0000000002" error="no" longcall="false" testcall="false" class="0" operator="false" correlator="2237103068041" connected="true">
<CallType>Local</CallType>
<Features>
<Feature>LineHunting</Feature>
<Feature>LegPartOfForwardedCall</Feature>
</Features>
<ReleasingParty>Orig</ReleasingParty>
<ReleaseReason type="q850" loc="u">16</ReleaseReason>
<ReleaseReason type="internal">No error</ReleaseReason>
<InternalIndex>194739965</InternalIndex>
<OrigParty xsi:type="MLHGPilotPartyType" subscribergroup="Subscribers" billingtype="msg rate" privacy="false" cpc="normal" ani-ii="00">
<SubscriberAddr type="e164">+15555555555</SubscriberAddr>
<CallingPartyAddr type="e164">+15555555555</CallingPartyAddr>
<ChargeAddr type="e164">+15555555555</ChargeAddr>
<BusinessGroupName>REDACTED-5555555555</BusinessGroupName>
</OrigParty>
<TermParty xsi:type="BusinessLinePartyType" subscribergroup="Subscribers" billingtype="msg rate" privacy="no indication">
<SubscriberAddr type="e164">+15555555555</SubscriberAddr>
<CallingPartyAddr type="e164">+15555555555</CallingPartyAddr>
<ChargeAddr type="e164">+15555555555</ChargeAddr>
<BusinessGroupName>REDACTED-5555555555</BusinessGroupName>
<UserAgent>PolycomVVX-VVX_450-UA/5.9.1.0615_64167f540a7b</UserAgent>
<SIPCallId>REDACTED@REDACTED</SIPCallId>
</TermParty>
<RoutingInfo>
<RequestedAddr type="unknown">15555555555</RequestedAddr>
<DestAddr type="e164">+15555555555</DestAddr>
<RoutedAddr type="national">5555555555</RoutedAddr>
<CallingPartyRoutedAddr type="national">5555555555</CallingPartyRoutedAddr>
<CallingPartyOrigAddr type="national">5555555555</CallingPartyOrigAddr>
</RoutingInfo>
<SignalingInfo>
<MediaCapabilityRequested>Speech</MediaCapabilityRequested>
</SignalingInfo>
<IcSeizeTime>1601447908233</IcSeizeTime>
<OgSeizeTime>1601447908242</OgSeizeTime>
<RingingTime>1601447908365</RingingTime>
<ConnectTime>1601447912631</ConnectTime>
<DisconnectTime>1601447994070</DisconnectTime>
<ReleaseTime>1601447994070</ReleaseTime>
<CompleteTime>1601447994070</CompleteTime>
</Call>
</CDRs>
<FileFooter>
<LastModTime>1601447994070</LastModTime>
<NumCDRs>2</NumCDRs>
<DataErroredCDRs>0</DataErroredCDRs>
<WriteErroredCDRs>0</WriteErroredCDRs>
</FileFooter>
</File>
```

When I run this against the XML, this is the output in JSON that appears in Kibana:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "nBs6fHkBZwvp-0WJpwp1",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "fields": {
    "path": [
      "PATH"
    ],
    "Call": [
      "Local",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "Orig",
      "16",
      "No error",
      "194739965",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "1601447908233",
      "1601447908242",
      "1601447908365",
      "1601447912631",
      "1601447994070",
      "1601447994070",
      "1601447994070"
    ],
    "Call.keyword": [
      "Local",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "Orig",
      "16",
      "No error",
      "194739965",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "1601447908233",
      "1601447908242",
      "1601447908365",
      "1601447912631",
      "1601447994070",
      "1601447994070",
      "1601447994070"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-05-17T21:28:09.157Z"
    ],
    "tags.keyword": [
      "multiline"
    ],
    "@version": [
      "1"
    ],
    "host": [
      "HOST"
    ],
    "@version.keyword": [
      "1"
    ],
    "host.keyword": [
      "HOST"
    ],
    "message": [
      "<Call seqnum=\"0000000002\" error=\"no\" longcall=\"false\" testcall=\"false\" class=\"0\" operator=\"false\" correlator=\"2237103068041\" connected=\"true\">\n<CallType>Local</CallType>\n<Features>\n<Feature>LineHunting</Feature>\n<Feature>LegPartOfForwardedCall</Feature>\n</Features>\n<ReleasingParty>Orig</ReleasingParty>\n<ReleaseReason type=\"q850\" loc=\"u\">16</ReleaseReason>\n<ReleaseReason type=\"internal\">No error</ReleaseReason>\n<InternalIndex>194739965</InternalIndex>\n<OrigParty xsi:type=\"MLHGPilotPartyType\" subscribergroup=\"Subscribers\" billingtype=\"msg rate\" privacy=\"false\" cpc=\"normal\" ani-ii=\"00\">\n<SubscriberAddr type=\"e164\">+15555555555</SubscriberAddr>\n<CallingPartyAddr type=\"e164\">+15555555555</CallingPartyAddr>\n<ChargeAddr type=\"e164\">+15555555555</ChargeAddr>\n<BusinessGroupName>REDACTED-5555555555</BusinessGroupName>\n</OrigParty>\n<TermParty xsi:type=\"BusinessLinePartyType\" subscribergroup=\"Subscribers\" billingtype=\"msg rate\" privacy=\"no indication\">\n<SubscriberAddr type=\"e164\">+15555555555</SubscriberAddr>\n<CallingPartyAddr type=\"e164\">+15555555555</CallingPartyAddr>\n<ChargeAddr type=\"e164\">+15555555555</ChargeAddr>\n<BusinessGroupName>REDACTED-5555555555</BusinessGroupName>\n<UserAgent>PolycomVVX-VVX_450-UA/5.9.1.0615_64167f540a7b</UserAgent>\n<SIPCallId>REDACTED@REDACTED</SIPCallId>\n</TermParty>\n<RoutingInfo>\n<RequestedAddr type=\"unknown\">15555555555</RequestedAddr>\n<DestAddr type=\"e164\">+15555555555</DestAddr>\n<RoutedAddr type=\"national\">5555555555</RoutedAddr>\n<CallingPartyRoutedAddr type=\"national\">5555555555</CallingPartyRoutedAddr>\n<CallingPartyOrigAddr type=\"national\">5555555555</CallingPartyOrigAddr>\n</RoutingInfo>\n<SignalingInfo>\n<MediaCapabilityRequested>Speech</MediaCapabilityRequested>\n</SignalingInfo>\n<IcSeizeTime>1601447908233</IcSeizeTime>\n<OgSeizeTime>1601447908242</OgSeizeTime>\n<RingingTime>1601447908365</RingingTime>\n<ConnectTime>1601447912631</ConnectTime>\n<DisconnectTime>1601447994070</DisconnectTime>\n<ReleaseTime>1601447994070</ReleaseTime>\n<CompleteTime>1601447994070</CompleteTime>\n</Call>\n</CDRs>\n<FileFooter>\n<LastModTime>1601447994070</LastModTime>\n<NumCDRs>2</NumCDRs>\n<DataErroredCDRs>0</DataErroredCDRs>\n<WriteErroredCDRs>0</WriteErroredCDRs>\n</FileFooter>\n</File>"
    ],
    "tags": [
      "multiline"
    ],
    "path.keyword": [
      "PATH"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1621286889157
  ]
}
```

Any tips or tricks to make it work as expected? I'd like to things like TrunkGroup, CallingPartyAddr, and ChargeAddr as fields. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You multiline codec will not extract valid XML. It will produce [message] fields like "<Call seqnum=\"0000000002\" error=\"no\" longcall=\"false\" testcall=\"false\" class=\"0\" operator=\"false\" correlator=\"2237103068041\" connected=\"true\">". The ruby filter does nothing because you do not create a field called [xml_value]. The xml filter will do nothing (not even produce an error) because there are no valid <Call> elements.

Comment: Is there a way to pull the full <Call> entity in or is it impossible because of the elements in the <Call> tag itself?